# Generate rails public cache from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, dynamically-generated

rails has a fantastic cache system.

But there is one thing that i haven´t figured out. How to generate a fragment cache directly from a rake task to prevent that the first user have to generate it.

Either generating it from a rake task every minute, or doing it directly in code when I know that a record has changed.